# Problem loading view on EVENT_RENDER_ERROR

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework2

I am new to ZF2 and it seems like I cannot do what I intended to.

The project I work on occasionally get some PDO Exceptions that I cannot catch at the moment so I want to have a generic function upon application load that will load a custom error page when such an exception occurs.

The 'exception_template' in global.php is not loaded when those exceptions happen so I created a function which I call upon EVENT_RENDER_ERROR where I basically want to load this view.

I tried things like:

```
$redirect_view = new ViewModel();
$redirect_view->setTemplate('error/exception');
```

also tried this:

```
$e->setViewModel()->clearChildren();
$e->setViewModel()->addChild($redirect_view);
$e->stopPropagation(true);
```

But I either get this error:

> [06-May-2019 15:11:19 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "exception"
>   ; resolver could not resolve to a file' in /var/www/vhosts/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:499

or this:

> #0 /var/www/vhosts/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Dashboard\Controller\InboxController->listAction()
>   #1 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))

I just want to load a plain view in case an unexpected error occurs throughout the entire project.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom error template for your module in different ways. The most common - and in my eyes easier way - is the approach by defining the template in the `module.config.php` file of your module.

```
return [
    'controllers' => [ 
        /* your controllers here */
    ],
    'routes' => [
        /* your routes go here */
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'exception_template' => 'error/exception',
        'template_map' => [
            'error/exception' => __DIR__ . '../view/error/exception.phtml'
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

As you can see, you can add an individuel template through the `template_map` option. Additionally add a new path to the template path stack and zend framework will walk the stack until the exception template is found.